# commit_id in repository's copies not equal

Tags: git

After:

```
git clone -b develop http://someurl.com
...
Updating working copy to revision 4539a1abd4e0c323ba38b1884cba85c57cd9d6fa
HEAD is now at 4539a1a Tidy
...
```

I have latest `commit id`:

```
git log -n 1
...
commit 4539a1abd4e0c323ba38b1884cba85c57cd9d6fa
...
```

But if do:

```
git ls-remote
...
a1d3d5c5661aba62245bec3f8f31b0b23b36d09c    refs/heads/develop
...
```

`commit id` == `a1d3d5c5661aba62245bec3f8f31b0b23b36d09c`

From manual we see:

> Displays references available in a remote repository along with the associated commit IDs.

ID `a1d3d5c5661aba62245bec3f8f31b0b23b36d09c` not found in `log` at all.

How can it be?

**EXT** In `master` branch - everything OK.

**UPD**

```
git branch -lvv
* develop 4539a1a [origin/develop: behind 2] Tidy
```

Comment: Could you please add the result of the command `git branch -lvv`?

Comment: @JérômeBrunel updated

Comment: It seems that you are behind by 2 commits so please try a `git pull`. If it does not resolve the issue, it might be that the history is has been rewritten. You have two solutions then: either execute a `git reset --hard origin/develop` therefore setting what is on your machine to be just like what is on the repo, or execute `git push -f` to do the opposite, setting the repository to be just like your local.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that someone updated branch `develop` on the remote while you were cloning.  This can happen with any repository, although it's more likely if your clone takes a long time (due to distance, a large repository, and/or a slow network link).

The same can happen with `git fetch`: by the time your fetch is done, you could be as much as several seconds out of date with the latest version. :-) Your git grabs the latest SHA-1 IDs during the operation startup (a la `git ls-remote`), then starts the process of bringing over the objects, and by the time you're all done it's possible new objects have been added and/or remote references have changed.  (Git does not hold a lock for the long duration of transferring the objects themselves.)

(The fact that `git branch -vv` shows you as being "behind 2" means your local git already has the updated `origin/develop` and the new commits and objects, and you can simply `git merge` or `git rebase` as usual to re-synchronize.)